# smarty pass values to php

Tags: php, smarty

I have a form in smarty template file like this

```
<div id="search-block-wrap">
  <table id="search">
    <tr>
      <td width="200" valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="search" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="search-here" type="submit" value="search" name="search" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here I want to pass the smarty varaibles to php where I can process the form. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this. Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: What Smarty variables? There aren't any in the code you've posted

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanna get the values of your input elements?

If so you have to use [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php) or [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php) - depending on which method your form uses.